# Why exited docker conatiner are not getting removed?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

File name: dockerHandler.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
to=$1
shift
cont=$(docker run -d "$@")
code=$(timeout "$to" docker wait "$cont" || true)
docker kill $cont &> /dev/null
docker rm $cont
echo -n 'status: '
if [ -z "$code" ]; then
    echo timeout
else
    echo exited: $code
fi
echo output:
# pipe to sed simply for pretty nice indentation
docker logs $cont | sed 's/^/\t/'
docker rm $cont &> /dev/null
```

But whenever I check the docker container status after running the the docker image it is giving list of exited docker containers.

command: docker ps -as

Hence to delete those exited containers I am running manually below command

rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)

Comment: Is your script running successfully to completion?  Does it output any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the flag `--rm` to your docker command:

From Docker man:

```
➜  ~ docker run --help | grep rm
  --rm             Automatically remove the container when it exits
```

Comment: I have tried this,
cont=$(docker run -d --rm "$@"). With this  exited containers are getting removed before execution completes. Please suggest

Comment: It look like your script is not finishing succesfully or getting error on the way. `--rm` shouldn't remove container before the execution completes. Can you share the script full output?

Answer (score 0):

removed lines 
     
docker kill $cont &> /dev/null
     
docker rm $cont 
     
docker logs $cont | sed 's/^/\t/'

and used gtimeout instead timeout in Mac, it works fine.

To install gtimeout on Mac:

```
Installing CoreUtils
brew install coreutils
In line 8 of DockerTimeout.sh change timeout to gtimeout
```